# Will MS Visual Studio 2012 work with Windows Vista?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I run windows vista business and want to try MS Visual Studio Express 2012. 
Are they compatible? Where is the compatibility list?

Comment: google for visual studio 2012 express, hit first or second link, click compatibility. Faster than asking on SO :]

Comment: @stijn - I somewhat disagree - considering that the redist silently "succeeds" but does not really install anything on Vistas, I would call that a trap.

Comment: When search on google stackoverflow often comes as first link with an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At least not officially: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/products/compatibility

Answer (score 6):

You can not install VS2012 on Windows Vista.

You will be able to target Vista with VS2012 but not with the public beta.  The beta redistributable, confusingly, [used to install](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/699143/vs-2012-redistributables-should-refuse-clearly-to-install-on-xp-vista) on Vista but did not work there.

There is no way of debugging or profiling applications installed on Vistas in VS2012.

This applies to both managed and unmanaged applications.

Comment: Is this the same story for Windows Server 2008 R1?

Answer (score -3):

No they are not compatible the update has to be atmost 2008