# Android emulator not running, can't find or load Qt platform plugin "windows"

Tags: android, android-emulator

When i run Android Amulator, it is showing error message below.
Does anyone know how to fix this problem ?
Thanks, in advance!
 :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyTzI.png)

Comment: See similar question here [Application failed to start because it could not find or load the QT platform plugin "windows"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268558/application-failed-to-start-because-it-could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platform-pl) Might help you solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to uninstall and reinstall the AVD component in the Andriod studio which worked for me
, you can give it a try